# Distraction-free Linux distro

Tags: linux-distribution

I'm a student who is easily distracted by any notifications that come on my computer. So, I want to install a distro that I use just for school stuff, and have it be as distraction-free as possible.

Requirements:

- Must support Google Chrome
- Have minimal to no notifications for software updating or anything
- KDE or Gnome
- No unnecessary applications installed (games, media software, etc.)
- Have LibreOffice or OpenOffice

Or, if anyone knows how to disable all notifications and all that jazz on Ubuntu, that works too.

Comment: set it to do-not-disturb mode. simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arch Linux, you install what you need only and update whenever you feel like it.

The install guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide

You can install chrome from the aur (you could use [yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt) to manage it) and it supports both kde and gnome fairly well.

Comment: A friend of mine also suggested Crunchbang Linux, so I'll try that too.

Comment: Archbang is basically archlinux easier to install. And about Google chrome, you should really use chromium from the official repos. You can install flash from the aur. See chromium in the ArchWiki.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I wouldn't waste time on Arch, because it would defeat the purpose of being just a distraction-free system. It's good for hobbyists that *want* to sink time into it. You'll be in an endless loop of tweaks, daily updates etc...

You can just install [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/) Workstation with GNOME. It encourages using one app at a time, thanks to workspaces. It also comes without a lot of bundled apps, and simply works out of the box. And in terms of notifications - you can just enable "Do-not-Disturb" with one click